# How to share a single C++ variable through a dll?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ file that outputs a string. How can I pass the string value to another file using a dll?

Code:

file name "importedfilewithvariable.h"

```
#include <string>

    int main(){
        std::string texttosend = "Hello World";
    
    
    }
```

File importing variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include importedfilewithvariable.h

int main(){
    std::cout << texttosend;


}
```

Comment: You can't have 2 main functions in a single executable.

Comment: why would you want that really?  it is much better to wrap it in a function

Comment: Are you trying to do "interprocess communication" (IPC)?  There are better ways to do this, for example messaging and memory-mapped files.

Comment: Dont want to put any data in just want to recieve the value of a current variable. Have 1 files that does calculation and then returns a result as a string. Want to have another file read that strings result but the second file is not inputing any data which is why not using a function because there is not data to input into the functions paramaters, Just looking to recieve the variables value. But perhaps there is a better approach. @AndersK

Comment: Why a DLL and not a message or text file in temp or IPC shared memory?

Comment: Perhaps that could work. Thanks very much @DaveS .

Comment: Allowing DLLs to have shared memory was a poorly thought out feature. There is no synchronisation, poor security, there are problems when they have different versions, it's not portable, among other problems. I don't think anyone uses that feature any more, and the world is better for it.

Comment: if i were you, i would wrap it in a function, instead of having a global variable on the loose. that way you can control the way other modules access it.